# Unable to connect to VM (RDP, Telnet, Ping)

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, rdp

We are unable to connect to our created VM in the cloud from our company (RDP, Telnet and ping).

We can do it from the VM to our company... so the Azure Tunnel is up.
We also able to connect to this VM if we use the public address

We try several thing, stop the firewall, adding endpoint.

Can you help us?

Thanks
Steve

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with MySQL server installed on VM, and endpoint TCP on port 3306 was defined exactly according to the guides, however couldn't connect from remote places not by MySQL or telnet.
I look for day's until I've checked -
Control Panel\System and Security\Windows Firewall\Allowed Programs
in the VM, and saw that for the program MySQL56 the public check-box was unchecked. 
checked it, and connection has open.